# Can I build a Word mergefield using other fields to complete the name?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, field-codes

I have a list of images (one per state) that I need to pull into my template and normally use a regular mergefield e.g., `{MERGEFIELD "Image_FL_09252017"}`. The image name is a combination of the state and date which I also have tags for, so I'm trying to create a dynamic mergefield to choose the correct image based on state and date.

Something along the lines of

```
{MERGEFIELD "Image_{MERGEFIELD "State"}_{MERGEFIELD "Date"}"}
```

However, Word seems to process the outside mergefield first instead of the inside mergefields. If I use an `IF` statement I can include static text to complete the mergefield, but as soon as I use another field it doesn't work. Is this something that's even possible within Word? Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You were so close with the IF field.  I used an IF field to test if the State was not empty, and then for the true condition (ie MERGEFIELD State <>"" - there is a State code for this record), insert the MERGEFIELDs for State and Date - noting that the fields and _ we want to insert are enclosed in punctuation marks.  The second "" is for the false condition (ie nothing in State field for this record so don't add any text).

[image]